# Rename [git-conflict-resolution] to [git-merge-conflict]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I propose renaming the tag [git-conflict-resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-conflict-resolution) to [git-merge-conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-merge-conflict).

- The name more clearly reflects the tag's usage for merge conflicts, [as per its description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/git-conflict-resolution/info).
- The naming order is more consistent with the existing tags [git-merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-merge) and [merge-conflict-resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/merge-conflict-resolution).
- It allows usage in questions that involve merge-conflicts without specifically asking how to resolve them. ([Example: Producing a git merge conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41757167/producing-a-git-merge-conflict))